# Get list of package family names at runtime?

Tags: uwp

I know how to get the package family name for the current UWP app: `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName`

How do I find the package family name for other UWP apps the user has installed?

Specifically I'm interested in apps for a certain protocol, and so [FindAppUriHandlersAsync(Uri)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.findappurihandlersasync) looked promising, but sadly that always returns an empty list for me.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

Here is the uri scheme registration in the apps I'm interested in:

```xml
<Application 
    ...>
    <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
        <uap:Protocol Name="my-great-protocol" ReturnResults="none">
        <uap:DisplayName>My Great Protocol</uap:DisplayName>
        </uap:Protocol>
    </uap:Extension>
    </Extensions>
</Application>
```

And it seems to work as launching my apps works:

```cs
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("my-great-protocol:"));
```

But this still returns an empty list:

```cs
var apps = await Launcher.FindAppUriHandlersAsync(new Uri("my-great-protocol:"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get list of package family names at runtime?

For your requirement, you could refer this [UWPTaskMonitor](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) code sample that use  `AppDiagnostic` api to get running UWP apps info. And this related [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) that you could refer.

**Update**

Derive from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.findappurihandlersasync#returns),

> A list of AppInfo objects representing each application that handles the specified http(s) URI.

`Launcher.FindAppUriHandlersAsync(Uri)` method could use to get app's info that you need to register to handle http and https links in the app manifest first, for the detail steps please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/web-to-app-linking#register-to-handle-http-and-https-links-in-the-app-manifest).

**Update 2**

For example:

```xml
<Application ...>
    <Extensions>
        <uap3:Extension Category="windows.appUriHandler">  
            <uap3:AppUriHandler>  
            <uap3:Host Name="my-great-host.com" />  
            </uap3:AppUriHandler>
        </uap3:Extension>  
    </Extensions>
</Application>
```

and

```cs
var apps = await Launcher.FindAppUriHandlersAsync(new Uri("http://my-great-host.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!  I think the `AppDiagnostic` sample you linked is only for running apps, but I'm interested in installed apps.

All the apps I'm interested in are actually my own apps, and I have registered my my own uri scheme (see updated question).  I know the registration worked because I can launch the apps via `await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("my-great-protocol:"));`.  Hence my confusion that `FindAppUriHandlersAsync()` returned nothing.

Comment: @Felix, Sorry guys, the previous reply is not complete, I have added the update please check.

Comment: Aah I see, `uap3:AppUriHandler` and `uap:Protocol` are two different things.  Hm, let me experiment a bit :)

Comment: Well, please let me know the result and if you have any updates you could add to the case update.

Comment: It worked :)  I added a `<uap3:AppUriHandler>` element and then `Launcher.FindAppUriHandlersAsync(...)` finds my apps.  Thanks a lot Nico!